# Is it wrong to send data in one thread?

Tags: c#

I want to send data in one thread, first I enqueue the data to the concurrentqueue, and the send thread loop sends if the `concurrentqueue.count >0`

```
private ConcurrentQueue < byte[] > sendBuffers;
private ManualResetEvent waitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
public void Send(byte[] data) {
  sendBuffers.Enqueue(data);
  waitEvent.Set();
}

public void SendFile(string fileName) {
  using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
    int count = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Const.NetDataSize];
    while ((count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, Const.NetDataSize)) > 0) {
      byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[count];
      Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, bytesToSend, 0, count);
      sendBuffers.Enqueue(bytesToSend);
    }
  }
  waitEvent.Set();
}
public async void Start() {
  await Task.Run(ProcessSend);
}

private async void ProcessSend() {
  if (sendBuffers.Count <= 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Total Send " + count + " bytes");
    waitEvent.Reset();
  }

  waitEvent.WaitOne();
  byte[] buffer;
  sendBuffers.TryDequeue(out buffer);
  try {
    count += buffer.Length;
    await stream.CancelableWriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, source.Token);
    ProcessSend();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("send exception: " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```

but at the client, I received the data is garbled, Is it wrong to write like this?

Comment: `Enqueue` is thread safe for the duration of a call to `Enqueue`. It's not thread safe over multiple calls from multiple threads.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the `bool` that is returned from `TryDequeue`. If the queue is empty it returns false, in which case you should not process `buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no guarantee that which all threads will get executed in order, you will need to define a structure that can tell the sequence number of the data

```
private ConcurrentQueue<(int, byte[])> sendBuffers;
```

The `int` component would be the index of the data and once you get all the results, you need to sort the list as per this index to restore the order of the data.

```
    int index = 0;
    while (...)
    {
        ...
        sendBuffers.Enqueue((index, bytesToSend)); // enqueue the data with its index
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: why would need an index and sorting if it's queued? a queue would maintain order.